# "Broadcast" or "Room" based Websocket Strategy

Tags: go, websocket, uwebsockets

What are the techniques or strategies behind the "**room**" based WebSocket connection or "**broadcast**" option in WebSocket?

Do we store "user's WebSocket connection ID" in a specific list for a room-based chat system?
And while emitting, do we "send/receive" a message using for loop to each participant/WebSocket-Connection-ID, or do we have an API to emit a message to all group users in one go without using loop?

I am using "gorilla WebSocket" - https://github.com/gorilla/websocket

If we store WS connection ID in a list, then if any room grows by 5000 participants, it will become extremely buggy to run a `for loop` to send/receive a message for each participants.

Please do not share any library, **I want to learn how room based chat system works or run in the backend**?

Comment: Telegram Chat has 5000 members limit in 1 group, do they really run `for loop` to emit messages to all 5000 members in millions of groups?

Comment: The service ultimately executes a write to each websocket connection.  There is no broadcast functionality in websockets or the underlying TCP layer.

Comment: HI @JohnCargo did you manage to solve this and broadcast asynchronously instead of looping over the connections? Grateful for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I built a web-socket [this](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) technique but modified it a little bit to support multi-room.

I created an hub for each room and stored the address of the hub in a map with key as string to make it easier to access each hub using the name of the room.

Now, the link provided above is an official example included in gorilla/websocket library and they have also neatly documented how it runs and behaves.I would recommend you to read that for better understanding of the example.

I will try to explain it in short.

The hub, which stores the list of people in the chat room runs as a go routine.
Each user will be allocated 2 go routines, one for receiving the incoming message one for sending the message back it's client. Apart from that each user gets a couple of unbuffered channels to store the data that was received or that is to be sent.

Suppose I send a message, the go-routine responsible for reading reads the message 
and passes it to a channel shared between it and the hub. Now the hub needs to broadcast the message to every person in the chat room. It simply iterates over the list users and passes the data using a channel(again, but a different one, not the one as before) to each of the go-routine responsible for sending the messages.

Remember that my explanation was just an overview and there are many details that  I didn't write since I will difficult to understand unless you have gone through the code, but the things I missed are give the docs for the example, so feel free to refer that.

Now coming back to 5000 participants question. The above method can handle that easily if they are not sending messages simultaneously which is very unlikely.
I faced a similar issue during my load test and was confused why my connections we crashing.

Turns out, the unbuffered channel was an issue, changing that to buffered channel(the size of buffer depends on the number of simultaneous messages).

So even with 5000 participants, the hub only need to pass the messages using a channel while the two go-routines do the heavy lifting.

PS: I you want to do any checks on the message, or database operation then do it on the read go-routine, not in the hub as to blocking of other messages.

Comment: `it simply iterates over the list users`, this is exactly what I don't want - Iteration of users and emitting messages one by one to each connection ID. Is there no WebSocket API to publish message to mass no. of users in 1 emit?

Comment: I am sure telegram chat uses a very different model, Telegram chat offers 5000 user limit in each group and messaging in that large group by telegram, I doubt `for loop` has any role.

Comment: I am not sure how telegram chat works. In the example by gorilla/websocket you iterate over the list and pass the messages to the channel, the hub doesn't directly deliver it. The hub passes the message to the writepump go-routine which then delivers the message to the client. The iteration won't consume much time as it isn't blocked by anything. It's the go-routine that actually delivers the messages and Golang is responsible for scheduling go-routines.

Comment: As for the API to publish in 1 emit, each user has a different connection(i.e. different address), so I can't see any other way than to  iterate over the  connections, unless I am wrong and there is a better method. Anyways, check these out: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/million-websockets-and-go-cc58418460bb/ https://github.com/gobwas/ws

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `uWebSockets`, there is a subscribe/publish mechanism. I am not sure if this mechanism is available in all server-side frameworks that support WebSockets.

The idea is really simple. You subscribe a WebSocket to a certain "topic", and you can publish messages to users belonging to that particular topic.

When you inspect the source code, it internally loops over what it calls `WebSocketContextData`. Which makes sense when you think about it in terms of TCP sockets. Every protocol out there is built upon either TCP or UDP.

Answer (score -2):

There is no "broadcast" to all users on websockets, you have to run through every user individually. This is the same from every library, you can take a look at 'uWebSockets' possibly the fastest websocket code that exists and it also has to do the same. Some can do it with shared ram buffers and zero memory allocation in places and run extremely efficiently. But you still have to run through everyone.